# Convert all the objects from bytes to a concatenated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bytesio

I have bytes (that I named content below) containing objects and I am trying to convert each object into a dataframe and to concatenate these dataframes into one dataframe using python.

```
print(content)
output: 
<Object url='https://...254383879.csv' etag='"fhksjdhfksjhfkwhefuhewuwiefuh"'>
<Object url='https://....603587330.csv' etag='"d317035287238579384759387452"'>
```

I tried the following code but it keeps running without any output:

```
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
df = []

for obj in content:
    obj = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(content))
   

df = pd.concat(df)
```

I also tried with this code:

```
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(content))
print(df[0:5])
```

But this second code would only convert the last object of content into a dataframe, not all of them. Does anyone know how to proceed to convert and concatenate all objects into one dataframe? thanks!

Comment: looks like you've done a real logic bomb! `for obj in content:
    obj = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(content))` makes no sense.  looping over lines in `content` and assign back to `obj`.  Plus `df = pd.concat(df)` where df has been initialised to an empty array.  Is this a public URL that you do `requests.get()` provide URL and will show how to process

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for you reply! unfortunately the URL is not public :( it would be extremely helpful if you could please post a sort of draft code or suggest a kind of logic i could use to solve this issue. Thank you so much for your help !